# How to convert an object array into a nested array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
array(4) { 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#19 (3) { ["column_name"]=> "article_id" 
    ["caption"]=> "Article Id" ["input_type"]=> "Number" }

    [1]=> object(stdClass)#21 (3) { ["column_name"]=> "issue_date" 
    ["caption"]=> "Issue Date" ["input_type"]=> "Date" } 

    [2]=> object(stdClass)#22 (3) { ["column_name"]=> "title" 
    ["caption"]=> "Title" ["input_type"]=> "Text" }
}
```

How can I convert it into an array like:

```
array(){
    ["column_name"]=> array('article_id', 'issue_date', 'title')
}
```

Comment: Loop over the array, collecting `$element->column_name` into a new array.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop then push each `column_name` to the new array

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $obj) {
    $result[] = $obj->column_name;
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<?php

// Create Data

$data = array();

$object1 = new stdClass();
$object1->column_name = 'article_id';
$object1->caption = 'Article Id';
$object1->input_type = 'Number';
$data[0] = $object1;

$object2 = new stdClass();
$object2->column_name = 'issue_date';
$object2->caption = 'Issue Date';
$object2->input_type = 'Date';
$data[1] = $object2;

$object3 = new stdClass();
$object3->column_name = 'title';
$object3->caption = 'Title';
$object3->input_type = 'Text';
$data[2] = $object3;

print_r($data);

// Parse Data

$col_names = array();

foreach ($data as $object) {
    $col_names[] = $object->column_name;
}

print_r($col_names);

?>
```

Visit [this link](https://eval.in/930172) to try a working demo.